# Why $_GET is not getting data from a different page?

Tags: php, forms, url, get

I have a form in a page and I redirect to another on form submission. I need to get the data from that form in the other page, but instead, I'm only getting the new page.

```
<form action='/busca' method="get">
   <input class='search__input' type='text' placeholder='Buscar por notícia' name='termo'>
</form>
```

and then inside the '**busca**' page:

```
    $resultados = 0;
    var_dump($_GET);
    if( isset($_GET['termo']) ) {
      $noticias = getNoticias()->rset;
      $resultados = array();
      $termo = $_GET['termo'];
      $counter = 0;
      foreach ($noticias as $id => $noticia) {
         if (strpos($noticia['titulo'], $termo) !== false) {
             $resultados[$counter]->titulo = $noticia['titulo'];
             $resultados[$counter]->id = $noticia['id'];
         }
      }
    }
```

When I type 'test' in the form, it redirects me to the page **busca** with the URL *http://localhost/escolas?termo=test*. But I don't get that data with my code. When I var_dump the $_GET it gives me:

```
array(1) { ["params"]=> string(5) "busca" }
```

But I need the 'termo' (in this case, 'test').

What can I do?

Comment: How are you submitting that form?

Comment: Along with how are you submitting the form, usually the html forms end up in POST variables, not in GET, so try checking the $_POST

Comment: When user hits enter, it goes to page 'busca'. I can't do it without a submit button?

Comment: At a guess, you have some url rewriting going on that's screwing things up.

Comment: Have you tried changing your `action="/busca"` to `action="/busca.php"` or something? As far as I know you had to prepare the extension of the file. If it isn't then kindly provide the complete simplified code of the app, it would help us to answer your question. ;)

Comment: @YomY The form is using `GET`, and I wouldn't say forms "usually end up in POST variables", because forms by default mostly use GET.

Comment: @FláviaNunes What is the var_dump if you have multiple input boxes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Decided to use POST instead. It works.

Comment: While using POST may resolve your current problem, it merely hides that you have problems elsewhere.